# CSS dropdown menu fine in FF and IE9 but drops to right in earlier IE versions

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

this question does seem to have been asked before with several different answers, none of which seem to work for me.

I have a css drop down menu that works fine in FF, Chrome and IE9 but in earlier versions of IE the menu is appearing on the right of the top level and therefore under the next item on the menu. See image below for FF on left IE8 on right.

Apparently I'm not allowed to post an image so you'll have to image it.

CSS is:

```
#newmenu, #newmenu ul 
{ 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0 
}

#newmenu li 
{ 
float: left;
position: relative; 
white-space: nowrap 
}

#newmenu li a 
{ 
display: block; 
padding: 5px 20px; 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #13a 
}

#newmenu ul 
{ 
background: #fff; 
display: none; 
float: left;
position: absolute
}

#newmenu ul li 
{ 
background: #1c2659; 
float: none 
}

#newmenu ul ul 
{ 
top: -1px; 
left: 100%
}

#newmenu li.has_child 
{ 
background-image: url('img/down.gif'); 
background-position: right center; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
padding-right: 10px 
}

#newmenu li.hover  
{ 
background-color: #2b397b 
}}
```

HTML here:

```
                <ul id="newmenu" class="clear">


                <li><a href='index.html'><span class="menuText"><strong>Home</strong></span></a></li>
                <li><a href=''><span class="menuText"><strong>About Us &#9662;</strong></span></a>

                    <ul>

                        <li>&nbsp;</li>
                            <li><a href='profile.html'><span class="menuText">Profile</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='people.html'><span class="menuText">People</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='referencemap.html'><span class="menuText">Reference Map</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='cpd.html'><span class="menuText">CPD</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='inspiration.html'><span class="menuText">Inspiration Newsletter &#9656;</span></a>

                            <ul>

                                <li><a href='inspsubscribe.html'><span class="menuText">Subscribe</span></a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>                               
                        <li><a href='changingworld.html'><span class="menuText">Changing World Newsletter &#9656;</span></a>

                            <ul>

                                <li><a href='chansubscribe.html'><span class="menuText">Subscribe</span></a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href=''><span class="menuText"><strong>Products &#9662;</strong></span></a>

                    <ul>

                            <li><a href='dalhem.html'><span class="menuText">Dalhem Panel </span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='geschwender.html'><span class="menuText">Geschwender &#9656;</span></a>

                            <ul>

                                <li><a href='locker.html'><span class="menuText">Lockers</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href='cubicle.html'><span class="menuText">Cubicles</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href='ductwall.html'><span class="menuText">Duct Walling</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href='vanity.html'><span class="menuText">Vanity Units</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href='accessories.html'><span class="menuText">Accessories</span></a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>
                            <li><a href='gustafs.html'><span class="menuText">Gustafs Panel System&#174;</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href=#><span class="menuText">Lighting &#9656;</span></a>

                            <ul>

                                <li><a href='architectural.html'><span class="menuText">Architectural</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href='event.html'><span class="menuText">Event</span></a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>
                            <li><a href='metra.html'><span class="menuText">Metra Electronic Locking</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='nappychanger.html'><span class="menuText">Nappychanger </span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='oranit.html'><span class="menuText">Oranit</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='texaa.html'><span class="menuText">Texaa Panels</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href='zsolnay.html'><span class="menuText">Zsolnay</span></a></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href=''><span class="menuText"><strong>News &#9662;</strong></span></a>

                    <ul>

                        <li><a href='2012.html'><span class="menuText">2012</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='2011.html'><span class="menuText">2011</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='2010.html'><span class="menuText">2010</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href='2009.html'><span class="menuText">2009</span></a></li>

                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href='contact.html'><span class="menuText"><strong>Contact Us</strong></span></a></li>

            </ul>
```

Any ideas gratefully received.
Thanks
Sarah

Comment: Unless someone already knows this by heart and can answer right away, you may want to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo.

Comment: its ok in IE 6-9 in IETester, maybe the rest of your code is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
#newmenu li.hover  
{ 
background-color: #2b397b 
}}
```

On the above line you have a double closing bracket. I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.

and is `.hover` a class or do you mean the pseudo element `:hover`?